# Php login script won't wrap around php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to verify that a user has logged in before showing them the page, using the method below, while the if/else method works when wrapped around plain html, it is failing when there is php involved.  I am a novice by the way.  What happens is the page simply loads as if the two tags below weren't there...which would be fine had I previously logged in, but I hadn't.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
?>

HTML/PHP Page goes here.

<?php
} else {
    header("Location: cms/admin/loginreadmode.php");
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can u explain more clearly! Atleast try post a fiddle snippet with sample code!

Comment: "it is failing when there is php involved"  It would probably help if you included that PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug just below your session_start(); by printing your session:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
die();
```

If $_SESSION['user'] isn't showing up in your array it isn't be set.
You can do this like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have add session support in every page?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { 
session_start(); 
}
```

This code should be working, so mistake is probably somwhere else I suggest checking if you set $_session["user] after login. 
You should also replace your not-working code part with simple

```
echo "hello";
```

to chek it.

Answer (score -1):

1) That is not a great method of checking whether a user is logged in, purely checking whether a user sessions exists can end up causing a lot of problems. Storing the ID in the sessions and then checking whether the ID is valid may be a better way,

2) When I copy the code above into a test document it goes straight to the redirect page in the else statement. This is down to the user session not being set, as soon as I set the user session before the code is executed it works fine. I see 'HTML/PHP Page goes here.'.

Setting the user session:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = 'TestUser';
```

Comment: How can we debug something we cannot reproduce it? If we cannot reproduce it, it must be something else. Which I covered in the last part of my answer.

Comment: "How can we debug something we cannot reproduce it". That's exactly my point. You cannot reproduce the issue, therefore you cannot give a true answer. This question lacks enough information to provide a meaningful answer. Further, the OP indicates that the problem exists _when not logged in_. This means that setting the session will not help, as it should not be set when not logged in. Content that should only be visible when logged in is being displayed to a non-logged-in user. Your "answer" in no way addresses this.

Comment: Ah, I see your point, my bad. I've just had to go and re-read the question several times and his problems becomes less and less clear.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes, 'I am unable to reproduce this issue' is an answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker While I respect and appreciate your input, how pray-tell could a close reason (Off-topic -> typo or unable to reproduce) also be a meaningful answer that is helpful to future users? Note that I did not actually flag this a NAA, I was just pointing out that this did not really address the issue in the question.

Comment: @PatrickQ "Not an answer" has a very specific meaning. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277272/not-an-answer-flag-declined/277281#277281

Comment: @GeorgeStocker As I said, I did not flag this as NAA. It is most certainly on-topic. However, nothing in the content of the "answer" actually addresses the issue the OP is having. Therefore, by definition, it is not an answer _to this specific question_. Could it, theoretically, be an answer to some other question? Sure, but not this one. I was trying to extend some courtesy to a low-rep user by informing them that their "answer" didn't address the issue instead of simply down-voting. I am quite aware of the official meaning of NAA. If I felt that it applied here, I would have flagged as such.

Comment: @PatrickQ The issue is that you can't say, This is "Not an answer" (on this site) when it is an answer according to this site.  It may not be an answer we encourage; but physically it is an answer. No, you didn't flag this as 'not an answer', but you left a comment saying it is 'not an answer'; which would give others the impression it'd be OK to flag it as "Not an answer". It wouldn't be; their flag would be declined.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the code at the top of the page to be

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
header("Location: cms/admin/loginreadmode.php");
die();
}
?>
```

Comment: This is just the inverse logic of what the OP is already doing.

Comment: @PatrickQ This will do the job he needs .. if he tried to check for session before adding <html> codes below